# Numbers $a^{p}a^q$ congruent to 1 modulo pq

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

Consider numbers of the form $a^{p}a^q=a^{p+q} $ where $p,q$ are primes.
Now I'm interested when such number is congruent to $1$ modulo product $pq$.

Take for example $p=3$ and $q=5$.
Then it seems that every number $a$ coprime with $p$ and $q$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $(pq)$.

For example
$7^8-1 \equiv 1 \pmod{15} , \ \   11^8-1 \equiv 1 \pmod{15},  \ \  13^8-1 \equiv 1 \pmod{15}  , \ \dots\ \ \    601^8-1 \equiv 1 \pmod{15} $ etc...

If we take $p=5$ and $q=7$ we have
$7^{12}-1 \equiv 1 \pmod{35} ,  \ \   11^{12}-1 \equiv 1 \pmod{35} , \ \   13^{12}-1 \equiv 1 \pmod{35}$, etc...

I don't know whether it is true for all $a$ but for pairs $(p,q)=\{(3,5),(5,7)\}$ I have   found no exceptions.

One could think that for others pairs of primes situation is similar however for pairs like $(11,13)$ or $(17,19)$ the pattern is not repeating.

For example $7^{11 + 13} \  \equiv 14 \pmod {11 \cdot 13}, \  17^{11 + 13} \  \equiv 53 \pmod {11 \cdot 13} $.

So my question:

- What are conditions imposed on pairs $(p,q)$ for which $a^{p+q} \equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$ holds?
- Why it holds for $(3,5)$ and $(5,7)$, ... for others probably not?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  Hmm, at first sight I don't see how to apply this Carmichael Function here..

Comment: We need $\lambda(pq)$ to be divisible by $p+q$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Is my concjecture for $(3,5)$ and $(5,7)$ is true ( for all $a$ coprime with them)? How to demonstrate that for these cases?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Could you present according to this principle others prime pairs not mentioned by me?

Comment: This will hold true for any positive integers $m,n$ if $$m+n$$ is divisible by $$\lambda(m,n)$$  Check the definition of $\lambda$

Comment: How about $18,12$

Comment: 18, 12 are not primes.  For them we have for example $7^{30}-1 = 2^4*3^2*11*19*31*43*191*2801*159871*6568801$

Comment: According to windows calculator $7^{30} \equiv 73 \pmod { 216= 18 \cdot 12}$

Comment: 15 and 17 are good it seems .. for them really $8=\lambda(15+17) | 32$

Comment: @Widawensen: Yes, $a^{15+17}\equiv 1\pmod{15\times 17}$ holds, but it is because $16=\lambda(15\color{red}{\times} 17)\mid 15+17$.

Comment: I'd try with some pseudoprimes or carmichael-numbers.

Comment: @mathlove  Really this Carmichael Function (unknown previously to me)  for 255 is equal 16 which is divisor of 32. But with this function I feel a little uncomfortable, it is like to replace one unknown with other unknown. However because this function was investigated the link to it is very valuable. It seems that there is no other systematic method of generating many pairs $(p,q)$ as to check table of values for Carmichael function ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

> - Why it holds for $(3,5)$ and $(5,7)$, ... for others probably not?

Let us prove that $a^{3+5}\equiv 1\pmod{3\times 5}$ if $\gcd(a,3\times 5)=1$.

We have$$a^{3+5}-1=a^8-1=(a-1)(a+1)(a^2+1)(a^4+1)$$

- If $a\equiv 1\pmod 3$, then $a-1\equiv 0\pmod 3$
- If $a\equiv 2\pmod 3$, then $a+1\equiv 0\pmod 3$
- If $a\equiv 1\pmod 5$, then $a-1\equiv 0\pmod 5$
- If $a\equiv 2,3\pmod 5$, then $a^2+1\equiv 0\pmod 5$
- If $a\equiv 4\pmod 5$, then $a+1\equiv 0\pmod 5\qquad\blacksquare$

Next, let us prove that $a^{5+7}\equiv 1\pmod{5\times 7}$ if $\gcd(a,5\times 7)=1$.

We have 
$$a^{5+7}-1=a^{12}-1=(a-1)(a^2+a+1)(a^3+1)(a^6+1)$$

- If $a\equiv 1\pmod 5$, then $a-1\equiv 0\pmod 5$
- If $a\equiv 2,3\pmod 5$, then $a^6+1\equiv 0\pmod 5$
- If $a\equiv 4\pmod 5$, then $a+1\equiv 0\pmod 5$
- If $a\equiv 1\pmod 7$, then $a-1\equiv 0\pmod 7$
- If $a\equiv 2,4\pmod 7$, then $a^2+a+1\equiv 0\pmod 7$
- If $a\equiv 3,5,6\pmod 7$, then $a^3+1\equiv 0\pmod 7\qquad\blacksquare$

---

As lab bhattacharjee commented, [Carmichael Function $\lambda(n)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html) might help.

$\lambda(n)$ is defined as the smallest integer such that $a^{\lambda(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$ where $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

So, we can say that $$\text{$p+q\ $ is divisible by $\lambda(pq)\quad\iff\quad a^{p+q}\equiv 1\pmod{pq}$}$$

For example, $$a^{3+5}\equiv 1\pmod{3\times 5}\quad\text{and}\quad a^{5+7}\equiv 1\pmod{5\times 7}$$ follow from $$\lambda(3\times 5)=4\quad\text{and}\quad \lambda(5\times 7)=12$$
which can be seen at OEIS [A002322](http://oeis.org/A002322).

---

**Added** :

If $q=p$, then
$$\lambda(pq)=\lambda(p^2)=p(p-1)$$
So, $$\lambda(pq)\mid p+q\implies p(p-1)\mid 2p\implies p=2,3$$
and it is easy to see that $a^{2+2}\equiv 1\pmod{2\times 2}$ and $a^{3+3}\equiv 1\pmod{3\times 3}$.

So, if $q=p$, $(p,q)=(2,2),(3,3)$ are the only such pairs.

If $q\not=p$, then
$$\lambda (pq)=\text{lcm}(\lambda(p),\lambda(q))=\text{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$$
So, $$\lambda(pq)\mid p+q\implies \text{lcm}(p-1,q-1)\mid p+q$$

So, if $q\not =p$, then in order to have $a^{p+q}\equiv 1\pmod{pq}$, we have to have $$\text{lcm}(p-1,q-1)\mid p+q$$

Comment: Very interesting method with use of polynomials. Thank you mathlove for comprehensive answer..

Comment: It's hard to say whether $(3,5)$ and $(5,7)$ are the only pairs of primes with assumed property. Up to product $<100$ I haven't found other one yet with the use of CarmichaelFunction table..

Comment: I've checked randomly   for some big primes that their products have rather very big values of $\lambda$ so the probability that they would be a divisors of $p+q$ is rather small..

Comment: @Widawensen: I added some explanations. We have $a^{2+2}\equiv 1\pmod{2\times 2}$.

Comment: Thank you, mathlove,  for   (2,2) pair. I used Table[Carmichaellambda[i*k],{k,20 },{i,20}] in WolframAlpha to generate symmetrical matrix  for small p,q<20 but received finally message  "Standard computation time exceeded" ... I have to postpone investigations..

Comment: @Widawensen: To be clear, if $q=p$, then $(2,2)$ is the only pair. If $q\not=p$, then in order to have $a^{p+q}\equiv 1\pmod{pq}$, we have to have $\text{lcm}(p-1,q-1)\mid p+q$.

Comment: Your  comment above is very important. Maybe it is worth to include in the main answer..

Comment: @Widawensen: Yes, I added them. And I was wrong. If $q=p$, then $(p,q)=(2,2),(3,3)$ are the only such pairs.

Comment: Very grateful to you, you put much meaningful effort for this problem..

Comment: I've generated at WolframAlpha matrix with formula Table[ (i+k+2) mod (lcm(i,k)), {i,25},{k,25}] . $\ \ \ (i=p-1, k=q-1)$. No zeros for primes beyond $(2,2), (3,3), (3,5), (5,7)  $ ... This evidence supports that these are the only solutions. As a bonus I have received from WolframAlpha that the constructed matrix is ... non-singular :)